# Web инструмент для командного планирования

Tags: менеджмент, планирование, метрики, team

Добрый день.

Существует ли онлайн система планирования совместной работы? С уклоном в совместную работу по программированию.

*ПС с праздником.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine неплохая штука. На работе юзаем, все довольны

Comment: у вас есть опыт работы с похожими системами? trac, bagzilla, jira?

Comment: Поставил redmine, буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: для багов юзаем Mantis, хотя он не очень удобный но так исторически сложилось, а из выше перечисленного нисчем не сталкивался)

Answer (score 1):

Мегаплан, например. Есть халявная версия с незначительными ограничениями.
А вообще, их полно. Просто с этой я довольно плотно работал.

Answer (score 1):

У нас когда-то давно руководство использовало в основном MS Project и таблицы Excel. А сейчас часть групп использует Team Player, часть ScrumWorks. И то, и то - по сути система онлайн планирования для программистов.

Comment: я как понимаю scrumWorks ставиться на свой сервер?

Comment: Думаю, да. У нас по политикам компании все должно на своих серверах размещаться.

Answer (score 1):

А мне вот этот сервис нравится http://freedcamp.com
Бесплатный аналог бэйзкампа (http://basecamphq.com)